# NullPointerException while populating views inside populateView using FirebaseListAdapter even when everything's right

Tags: firebase, android-studio, listview, listadapter

The populateView method of FirebaseListAdapter is throwing null pointer exceptions while trying to set text of individual text views even though the layout id, view ids are correct. Here's the main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private String dbUrlString = "MY_DB_URL_HERE";
private ListView listView;
private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
private FirebaseListAdapter<Video> adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Fetching",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(dbUrlString);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    FirebaseListOptions<Video> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<Video>()
            .setQuery(databaseReference,Video.class)
            .setLayout(R.layout.custom_item_layout)
            .build();
    adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Video>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(@NonNull View v, @NonNull final Video video, int position) {
            TextView vname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.video_name);
            TextView vId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.video_list_id);
            vname.setText(video.getName());
            vId.setText(video.getVideoId());
        }
    };
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    adapter.startListening();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    adapter.stopListening();
}
}
```

This is the main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

These are the views in the custom_item_layout file with the respective ids:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/play_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_play_video_24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/video_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/play_icon"
        android:text="Video title"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/video_list_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="."
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the Video class:

```
package com.example.util;

public class Video {
private String name, videoId;

public Video(){

}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getVideoId() {
    return videoId;
}

public void setVideoId(String videoId) {
    this.videoId = videoId;
}

public Video(String name, String videoId) {
    this.name = name;
    this.videoId = videoId;
}
}
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.gifapplication.MainActivity$1.populateView(MainActivity.java:44)
    at com.example.gifapplication.MainActivity$1.populateView(MainActivity.java:39)
    at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter.getView(FirebaseListAdapter.java:121)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2365)
    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1408)
    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1315)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22759)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6788)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1167)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:687)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22759)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6788)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22759)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6788)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:403)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22759)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6788)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22759)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6788)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22759)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6788)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:754)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22759)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2538)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1565)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1833)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1453)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7039)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:924)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:732)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:664)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:910)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6524)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:888)
```

Any help is appreciated. I've been going crazy trying to fix this. Tried a couple of fixes suggested online but nothing works. I don't even get why the views are null even when they're being instantiated with the right ids.

Comment: In `populateView()`, you need to call `findViewById()` on the `View` passed into that method; e.g., `TextView vname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.video_name);`. As you have it now, you're calling `findViewById()` on the `Activity`, which won't have those `TextView`s.

Comment: Hey Thanks a ton! It worked. If you could put it as an answer too, I'd love to mark it accepted and I'm sure it'd help someone else too